# hadoop distinct count of a field

Tags: java, hadoop

i have a file whose format is like below:

1,5321234567
1,5324564321
1,5324564321
2,1234567643
2,1234567666
2,9875422345
3,5344435345
3,5344435345
3,5344435345
3,5344435345
3,5345345312
3,8767564564

At the end of the reduce process,  i want a distinct counts of the second field with the first field is the key. e.g.

1,2
2,3
3,3

What are the simplest map and reduce functions in Java for this purpose?

Tnx.

Comment: Parse the lines and add each line to a Map<String, Set<String>>.
For example after the third line you would have [1, {5321234567, 5324564321}]
 The reduce step simply returns the Set size for each key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly you'll need to :

1. Make the values per key unique
2. Count the number of distinct items per "key"

So the simplest way to get there would be something like this:

Assume the input is {A,B}

```
MAP 1:
   Output Key  : {A,B}
   Output Value: 1
REDUCE 1:
   Input Key   : {A,B}
   Input Values: {1,1,1,...}
   Output Key  : A
   Output Value: B

MAP 2:
   Output Key  : A
   Output Value: 1
REDUCE 2:
   Input Key   : A
   Input Values: {1,1,1,...}
   Output Key  : A
   Output Value: SUM of all the values
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you need count of unique values for a key and not to preserve values.
It would we simple by creating key from record, rest hadoop framwork will take care of sorting unique records for you.

```
    map (IntWritable key, Text value, Context context) {

       context.write(value, new IntWritable(1)); 
    }

    reduce (Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) {

         long count = 0;
         for (Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
              count+= iterator.next().get();
         }

         context.write(key, new LongWritable(count));
      }
```

Reducer can be used as combiner as well.

Comment: This would put all values in memory. Very bad idea.

Comment: Ya that's right... i was just giving example for using Set..as i mentioned...its not perfect in my explanation.....

Answer (score -3):

Just do Sorting. Get all the inputs in the arraylist and do sorting.

This would help you

[Array](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-library.html)

Comment: ArrayLists don't scale into Hadoop.